# ReactJS -> Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am super new to React, I was following the tutorial online. In the tutorial we had already made an App using class based components and not that it was time to change it to function based components. My App was working when it was using class based component, but when I switched it and tried using hooks I am getting this error.

Code that maybe causing it:

```
import NewsItem from './NewsItem'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Spinner from './Spinner';
import InfiniteScroll from "react-infinite-scroll-component";

function NewsView(props) {

    const [articles, setArticles] = useState([])
    const [page, setPage] = useState(1)
    const [totalResults, setTotalResults] = useState(10)

    const update =  async () => {
        props.handleProgress(0)
        let url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?&category=${props.category}&country=${props.country}&apiKey=${props.key}&pageSize=${props.pageSize}&page=${page}`
        const response = await fetch(url);
        props.handleProgress(30)
        let data = await response.json();
        props.handleProgress(70)
        props.handleProgress(100)
        setArticles(articles.concat(data.articles))
        setTotalResults(data.totalResults)
    }

    const fetchMoreData = () => {
        setPage(page + 1)
        update()
    }

    useEffect(() => {
            update()



    }, [])
    return (

        <div className='container my-2 '>
            <div className={`container text-center my-4 text-${props.darkmode ? "light" : "dark"}`}>
                <h1>Top {props.category[0].toUpperCase()}{props.category.slice(1)} Headlines</h1>
            </div>
            <InfiniteScroll
                dataLength={articles.length}
                next={fetchMoreData}
                hasMore={articles.length < totalResults}
                loader={<Spinner />}
            >
                <div className="row d-flex justify-content-center" >
                    {articles.map((article, index) => {
                        if (article.urlToImage != null) {
                            return (
                                <div className="col" key={index}>
                                    <NewsItem darkmode={props.darkmode} title={article.title} description={article.description} url={article.url} urlToImage={article.urlToImage} author={article.author} time={article.publishedAt} source={article.source.name} ></NewsItem>
                                </div>)
                        }
                        return null;
                    })}
                </div>
            </InfiniteScroll>
        </div>
    )
}

NewsView.propTypes = {
    category: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    country: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    pageSize: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    darkmode: PropTypes.bool.isRequired,
    handleProgress: PropTypes.func.isRequired,

}
//set default props
NewsView.defaultProps = {
    darkmode: false,
}

export default NewsView
```

I have tried adding useCallback to update the function and adding a condition to make it run if its true and then turn it false i.e just make it false after one run.

I am not able to figure out whats wrong
here is what I am getting in terminal:

```
[eslint] 
src/components/NewsView.js
  Line 35:8:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'update'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.

WARNING in [eslint] 
src/components/NewsView.js
  Line 35:8:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'update'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

webpack compiled with 1 warning
```

and **here is the error in console**

```
Uncaught Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16317:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26434:1)
```

Comment: in your dependency array add articles and totalResults

Comment: Define the function in useEffect  and add props to the dependency array

Comment: This is often caused by a `useEffect` that has a state that's being updated as a dependency. For example, if  you were to call `setArticles` in a `useEffect` and have `articles` as a dependency, it would loop forever.

Comment: @Jeroen but I need to add more articles to articles, useEffect it runs first and fills up the data then update  is called again when scrolling through the supplied articles. How can I do that

Comment: @Prem I needed to add a code snippet, so I have submitted an answer as response to your comment.

Comment: You should have a look at React-Query by the way. It's a library that handles pagination and infinite queries for you. Works really well!

Answer (score 0):

This is often caused by a `useEffect` that has a state that's being updated as a dependency. For example, if you were to call `setArticles` in a `useEffect` and have `articles` as a dependency, it would loop forever.

You could still use a `useEffect` to update the articles. If you compare the new and old articles and only call `setArticles` if they're different. This could be done as following

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (newArticles !== oldArticles) {
    setArticles(newArticles)
  }
}, [newArticles])
```

Be careful with the checking here, JS doesn't like comparing objects, so you might need to write a function that checks every object in the array. Not sure though.

Also make sure to implement a null-check when rendering the state. This will prevent the page from crashing when there's a problem with fetching the articles. An example would be:

```
return (
  <>
    {
      // Simply checking if there are articles
      filteredArticles
        ? 'There are articles' 
        : 'No articles'
    }
    {
      // Or printing individual articles
      filteredArticles && filteredArticles.map((article) => <Article article={article} />)
    }
    {
      // Null checking with Typescript
      filteredArticles?.map((article) => <Article article={article} />)
    }
  </>
)
```

Comment: Hi, I only want useEffect to run once like didcomponentmount in class based components.
i will update the new articles using a different method

Comment: @Prem In that case, use an empty dependency array (the [] part). This will automatically fill the state upon first render. Make sure to implement a null-check when rendering the state. E.g. `{filteredArticles ? 'There are articles : 'No articles'}`